# How to query a 2D grid with a rectangle that contains a rectangle

Tags: algorithm, grid, rectangles

[image]

I have a 1D grid like the one above. The green rectangle is an object in the grid and the blue rectangle is the range that this object's effect covers. The green rectangle can be of any size(width and height) and the blue rectangle will expand this rectangle by X cells in all sides, unless it is in one of the corners of the grid in which case it won't expand that side. I want to obtain the cells in blue and give them a separate value from the cells in green. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: If shape of the green area is always rectangle, {blue + green} area is also rectangle, and it looks like that calculating it is just simple arithmetic. So... I don't understand what is your real problem.

Comment: @fana I want to give them different values. If I iterate over the blue rectangle, I know that I will also have the green rectangle, however, I need to check for the cells in the green rectangle to give them a different value. I need to know how to do this efficiently

Comment: That grid has width and height. It's a two dimensional grid. A "1D grid" is nothing but an array like `int a[10]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
for row  = max(0, bottom - x) to min(height-1, top + x):  
    for col  = max(0, left-x) to min(width-1, right + x):  
        if (row < bottom) or (row > top) or (col < left) or (col > right):
            cell[row][col] = blue
        else: 
            cell[row][col] = green
```

If rectangles are large and you need only blue cells, then it is cheaper to walk through 4 regions of width X

Comment: @nico.user Is my answer unclear? Or I erroneously read the question?